# Connect multiple WMS layers in CARTO querying to GetFeatureInfo

Tags: wms, carto, getfeatureinfo

Connect multiple WMS layers in CARTO querying to GetFeatureInfo. How do I get GetFeatureInfo information from the attached WMS layer?

Comment: Have you been able to add one/ multiple WMS services/layers to carto?  Are you able to do a GetFeatureInfo request on any of them?